# top 10 from sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to retrieve the `ID` and `DATE` fields for the top 10 upcoming from my table.

Without the `ID` the query below works:

```
select top 10 MAX(FromDate) as upcomingdates 
from TM_Schedule 
group by(FromDate)
```

But if I add the `ID`, it throws an error:

```
select top 10 MAX(FromDate) as upcomingdates, ID 
from TM_Schedule 
group by(FromDate)
```

Comment: please specify which error is thrown :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your data, but it looks like you can accomplish that without `GROUP BY` or `MAX`. Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ID, FromDate
FROM TM_Schedule
ORDER BY FromDate DESC
```

It should work, unless you have multiple `FromDate` values for the same `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select FromDate as upcomingdates, ID from TM_Schedule 
WHERE FromDate IN 
( 
   select top 10 MAX(FromDate)as upcomingdates from TM_Schedule group by(FromDate)
)
ORDER BY FromDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
select top 10 MAX(FromDate)as upcomingdates, ID 
from TM_Schedule group by(FromDate), ID
```

You need to group by ID also